# Problem when receiving data in Angular from the BackEnd part

Tags: angular, http, observable

I hope you are well, I encountered a small problem when I wanted to develop an Angular application , what I wanted exactly is to bring back a list of element "Menu" of my backend part to use it in my application.

The problem is that when i use the get method to bring back the data, this data is brought back to the end of the execution, i noticed this detail when i wanted to log the objects that i bring from the backEnd in console.

[image]

As you can see,when I log the MenuItem object in the constructor or in the Onint () method I get an empty object but when I log this object in the service class I get the menuTtem object, so  I understand that the OnInit and Construtor are executing first and following the method http get in second.

My question is this:
is there a way to recover the data without falling into this problem ?

here is my constructor in menu.component:

```
constructor(public appSettings: AppSettings, public menuService: MenuService) {
  this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
  console.warn('this.menuItems in the construtor', this.menuItems)
```

}

and the getMenuItems () method of my Menu.service service

```
public getMenuItems(): Menu[] {
  this.http.get<Menu[]>(this.url + 'all').subscribe(
      data => { this.menudata = data
        console.warn('this.menudata in Service', this.menudata)
    }
  )
  return this.menudata ;
```

}

If there is any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Comment: what is your `this.appSettings.settings` line returns...

Comment: well, it is not related to the context, the problem is in the " this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to me it seems the code works as it should. You just need to understand the asynchronous nature of JS. You can't block the main JS thread with inherently slow network communication (a HTTP request-response roundtrip might take 200ms).

In this case the `get` function returns an `Observable` on which you can `subscribe` to new events. And that's it. In this case the event is a HTTP response. When HTTP response arrives it will assign the `data` to `this.menudata` and log the service message.

So, you `subscribe` to the `Observable` immediately but the subscription itself gets processed when a HTTP response arrives. It can't wait for the response and then continue. It would kill app's responsiveness.

// For more info about the concept, use relevant part of the official [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data).

Comment: Is there any way to work with synchronous request in Angular, and if it exists do you think it can solve the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to work with the `this.menudata` in a synchronous way? Just process them in a callback when the response arrives.

Comment: in fact I want to retrieve the menu list inside the component menu, that why i wanted this list at once.

Comment: The at once requirement sounds odd. Maybe the official Angular guide might come handy: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data

Comment: I guess you're right , i changed my code to proccess in the call back, and it work for me, thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 0):

call your methods in `ngOnInit()` not in the constructor. When the `getVerticalMenuItems()` method is called, the thread is not waiting for the response so the parameter returning `undefined`. That's why you are getting undefined there.

do some changes like below,

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
      this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
      console.warn('this.menuItems in the construtor', this.menuItems)
  } 



 public getMenuItems() {
  this.http.get<Menu[]>(this.url + 'all').subscribe(
      (data: any) => { 
        this.menuItems = data
        console.warn('this.menuItems in Service', this.menuItems )
    }
  )
}
```

It's a better practice to subscribe your Observable response in Component.

Comment: I did the change you told me but Sadly i get the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to Observable inside the component so that the data that is coming from the backend are reachable inside of the component.

notice that when you call getMenuItems() method of the Menu.service it returns the data that is assigned to menudata property in that particular time which is null in case of first call of the method.

that is happening because the observable is getting the over time "there is a delay" or in other words it is async operation

```
 public getMenuItems(): Observable<Menu[]> {
  return this.http.get<Menu[]>(this.url + 'all');
  }
```

and inside of you component

```
ngOnInit () {
this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems().subscribe((data) => {
   this.data = data;
});

}
```

Comment: I just changed my following your approach but get errors !      
SidebarComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: that is because you are doing ngFor on an element that is not initialized yet
try wrapping it up with ngIf directive or have a look at async pipe
or..
initialize your this.data = [ ];

Answer (score 0):

try this: subscribe to your API call in your ngOnInit() and not your services component

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
      this.menuService.getMenuItems().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {  
        console.warn('this.menuItems in Service', data )
    }
  );

  }
```

in your service component, do this. Do not forget to return the service call

```
 public getMenuItems() {
 return this.http.get<Menu[]>(this.url + 'all')
}
```

Comment: when i log the value of Menu i get : "this.menuItems undefined" and after i get errors : "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" why do i get undefined  ?

Comment: You have to declare menuItems in your component, just above your constructor.